# Increment name tag for cloned elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with cloned elements. The method of the form is `POST`. When I dump the result of the POST only the final 'select' box value is shown because they are all the same. How can I change the `name` tag to the cloned elements?

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/hLefegxz/

**HTML**

```
<div id="employees-div">
<label for="employees">Employee(s)</label>
<div class="select-wrapper" id="select-employees">

    <select id="employees" name="employees" >
        <option value="" selected disabled>- Select Employee -</option>
        <option value="1"> Jason Bourne </option>
        <option value="2"> James Bond </option>
        <option value="3"> Ethan Hunt </option>
    </select>

</div>
```

**JS for the Clone**

```
$(function() {
    $("#addMore").click(function(e) {
        var newSelect = $("#select-employees").clone();
        newSelect.val("123");
        $("#employees-div").append(newSelect);
     });
});
```

At the moment all fo the elements have the same name tag of employees. It obviously needs to be different to go into the $`_POST` `array`. How can I go about making them different? I was thinking maybe of incrementing and keeping a count? It Currently is like so:

[image: All name tags are the same]

Comment: is enabling multiple selection for the select element an option?

Comment: No, not really. You should only be able to select one item from each of the select boxes.

Comment: You could name the select to `employees[]` and you'll have an array server side.

Comment: Want to make that an answer @Karl-AndréGagnon? Worked for me!!

Comment: @Nouman I did, glad it helped you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a name and increasing an integer on each "new employee", you could simply name your select to `employees[]`. That will send every employee in an array format to your server, allowing you to use an easy loop.

Your code as another problem though. ID should be unique, so every time you clone your `select`, you should change the ID.

Comment: Would the downvoter kindly explain the reason? This very answer solved OP problem.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce., yes, but I posted a comment that solved the issue, OP asked me to make it an answer, and you post your answer 30 seconds before mine. That does not deserve a downvote IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about changing the name, you can and should use an array for the name, but you should worry about the id, since ids must be unique and you are cloning elements without changing the id of the new element.

By adding the `[]` to the input name it will be sent to the server as an array, for example, if you're using PHP you can get them from `$_GET['employees']` which will be an array you can loop thru.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#addMore").click(function(e) {
        var newSelect = $('select[name="employees[]"]:first').clone();
        $("#select-employees").append("<br>");
        $("#select-employees").append(newSelect);
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="employees-div">
<label for="employees">Employee(s)</label>
<div class="select-wrapper" id="select-employees">

    <select name="employees[]" >
        <option value="" selected>- Select Employee -</option>
        <option value="1"> Jason Bourne </option>
        <option value="2"> James Bond </option>
        <option value="3"> Ethan Hunt </option>
    </select>

</div>
<button id=addMore>+ Employee</button>
```